# Hyperledger composer got stuck when upgrading the network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Here are the steps that I went through:

1. Stop and tear down fabric
2. Start fabric
3. Create a Business network using yo `hyperledger-composer`
4. Create .bna archive and install it
5. Start network with version 0.0.1
6. Import card to the playground

All these steps work fine, but when I start playground and try to upgrade business network with my changes, in a browser it gets stuck on

```
Please Wait: Your new business network is being upgraded
Upgrading business network using PeerAdmin@hlfv1 (2/2)
```

and never responds

Here what I see in logs of composer--playground:

> info: [Hyperledger-Composer] :ConnectionProfileManager :getConnectionManagerByTyp Looking up a connection manager for type 0=hlfv1

Maybe someone has already faced this kind of issue and knows how solve it? Or in the local environment, I should upgrade it manually?

- P.S I am new to Composer, so all these steps I found in the
  [Developer tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `composer network upgrade` command and its equivalent action in the Composer Playground generate a new docker "chaincode image" and "chaincode container".  Creating the image and starting the container is what takes the time.  You will see that you now have redundant docker containers and images of previous versions of the Business Network.  This is intended behaviour of Hyperledger Fabric (and Composer) but you may want to do some housekeeping to remove the old versions.

If you are in early versions of development and experimentation - generating lots of versions of Networks, you can use the 'Web Profile' in the Playground which simulates a Fabric in the LocalStorage of the Browser - it is much faster but if you use it be sure to periodically export to a BNA otherwise you might lose work if there is a browser issue or upgrade.

**Updated following Comment**

The command `docker ps` can be used to see all running containers (`docker ps -a` will also show stopped containers.)  `docker stop` is used to stop a container and `docker rm` to remove the container.

Docker *containers* are running (or stopped) instances of docker *images* so you will also want to remove the redundant images.  You list the images with `docker images` and remove them with `docker rmi`.

The docker web site has a full list of commands.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how to see what docker images I have , and how to delete redundant?

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, but the process of upgrading the network took more time than I thought, so the solution will be simple:

> Wait 3-4 minutes until the process finishes and do not click anywhere
>   in the browser (by mistake I tried to reconnect to the card, and in
>   that case, the process of upgrading fails).

Additionally, important to mention, in the manual process of upgrading of the card(using CLI), it takes the same amount of time